# Spring cloud stream writing in two databases

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, sink

I have a spring cloud stream situation where I have one source, one transformer and I need to write in two databases the same thing. I was checking if there is an option to have two sinks but I can't find a way to do that.
Any suggestion in best practice for my case would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple sinks listening to the same destination see [consumer groups](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/1.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/index.html#consumer-groups).

Each group gets a copy of the message.

**EDIT**

If you are using spring-cloud-dataflow, you can use a tap:

```
stream create foo --definition="source | transform | sink1"

stream create bar --definition=":fooLtransform > sink2"
```

Comment: So are you suggesting that my sink should be a Kafka topic and have two other streams that listen to those topics and write to two different sinks

Comment: There is no need for an explicit Kafka sink; if you are defining your streams with spring-cloud-dataflow, you can use a tap as the source for the second stream - [see taps](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-tap-dsl). I added an example. If you are writing stand-alone spring-cloud-stream apps, you can simply configure them both to listen to the same destination.